# mysql can not compare data and parse it with php

Tags: php, mysql, md5

i'm getting back to make some php code to make a login/register form.
Account data is stored in mysql database and I've used that code to validate the md5 and parse it trough the browser. But there's something wrong 'cause it doesn't work.

```
<?php
    if (!$x) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='index.php';</script>";
    } else {
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'userdb', 'pwd') or die(mysql_error());
        $db = mysql_select_db('dbname', $con) or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `md5pwd` = '". $x ."'");
        $num = $result1->num_rows;
        if($num == 0){
            //if not display an error message
            echo "<script> alert('Usuario inexistente') </script>";
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        }else{
            while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result1)){
                $userName=$row->username; 
                echo "<script> alert('BIENVENIDO " . $userName . "') </script>";
                echo "[ " . $userName . " ]\n\n";
            }
        }       
    }
?>
```

I hope you can understand and I hope you can help me. I'm unhappy.

thanks

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? Blank screen? An error messages? Lets everyone in? Lets no one in? Lets you in some of the time?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: What is the value of `$x`?

Comment: I login correctly but always display the error message 'cause $num == 0

Comment: The question is not clear, the value of X is unknown, No information about the error is given. How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: You have `$result = mysql_query...` and you're using `$num = $result1->num_rows;` when you should be using `$result1 = mysql_query...` @RaphaelD.G

Comment: I've been 1 year out of programming anything. I'm so sorry about it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope it helps you, `$num = mysql_num_rows($result);` instead of  `$num = $result1->num_rows;`

`mysql_fetch_object($result)` instead of `mysql_fetch_object($result1)`

```
<?php
    if (!$x) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='index.php';</script>";
    } else {
        $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'userdb', 'pwd') or die(mysql_error());
        $db = mysql_select_db('dbname', $con) or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `md5pwd` = '". $x ."'");
        $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($num == 0){
            //if not display an error message
            echo "<script> alert('Usuario inexistente');document.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        }else{
            while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                $userName=$row->username; 
                echo "<script> alert('BIENVENIDO " . $userName . "') </script>";
                echo "[ " . $userName . " ]\n\n";
            }
        }       
    }
?>
```

**Note:** mysql_* functions deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: and what about `$result1` ?

Comment: ...and there you have it. ;-)

Comment: Yes Fred, It is because of you. Thanks lot once again.

Comment: We're all in this together, you're very much welcome. Call it a "joint effort" ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Working code:

```
 <?php

        if (!isset($x)) {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        } else {
            $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'userdb', 'pwd') or die(mysql_error());
            $db = mysql_select_db('dbname', $con) or die(mysql_error());
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `md5pwd` = '". $x ."'");
            $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if($num == 0){
                //if not display an error message
                echo "<script> alert('Usuario inexistente') </script>";
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location.href='index.php';</script>";
            }else{
                while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)){
                    $userName=$row->username; 
                    echo "<script> alert('BIENVENIDO " . $userName . "') </script>";
                    echo "[ " . $userName . " ]\n\n";
                }
            }       
        }
    ?>
```

PS: mysql_extension will be removed in the future, use mysqli or PDO...btw mysqli in procedural mode it's very similar to mysql extension.